# Session Variable value from DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session

I have a web application which calls a DLL, this dll gets some of the data from a webservice. What I would like to do is when a user logs into the web app, i'm currently storeing it's username in a session variable. In my webService i have a WebMethod like this:

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string getLoggedInUsername()
    {
        SessionManager session = new SessionManager();

        return session.Username;
    }
```

This works fine, however when i access the webservice from the DLL, the value returned is always NULL, this is because when the console app connects to the webservice a new session will be initialized. Is there any alternative how can i store the logged in username and pass it to the dll through my webservice? Using Application Get/Set is not a good decision since my webapp needs to handle different users. Anyone could point me in the right direction?

The SessionManager class contains the following:

```
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"];
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] = value;
        }
    }
```

after the user logs into my application (i'm using asp.net membership) : i assign the username to the session variable in this way:

```
            SessionManager session = new SessionManager();
            session.Username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, that user name stored in session, is it in the webservice's session or the web app's session?

Comment: i have updated my question Medinoc so you can get a better picture

Comment: Thanks. However, in "when the console app connects to the webservice" you speak of a previously-unmentioned console application. What is its role in this? Also, your third code snippet, is it in the web app?

Comment: i'm sorry that was my typo, the console app is the DLL. i typed in console app since i always tried it from a console app in order to debug.

Comment: no the DLL is not in my web app. it's a separate dll. basically the dll contains nunit tests, which are called from the web app.

Comment: The DLL is "called from the web app" but not "in the web app"?? How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service 
You may have to re-initialize the proxy and the cookie container